# Entity Framework in Parallel, how to update database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(recipients, pOptions, (item, state) =>
{
     using (Entities ent = new Entities())
     {
         Campaign camp = ent.Campaigns.Where(xx => xx.CampaignID == campaignID).FirstOrDefault();
         camp.Sent = Camp.Sent + 1; 
         ent.SaveChanges(); 
     }
}
```

The problem is that the save changes are not persisted with the DB.

EDIT: Neither is the value persisted among other threads.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering whether an exception is being swallowed. That code scares me.

Comment: Its a simplification of the code to demonstrate the area of concern.

Comment: I reworked the code not to update the DB per record, still its a bit concerning....

Comment: I might be wrong, but you haven't done a db add? before saving changes? so something like ent.Campaigns.add(camp); then you do a ent.SaveChanges();, but if you are doing am edit you would have ent.Entry(camp).State = EntityState.Modified;  Though I know this is a really old post

Answer (score 1):

It save to call **SaveChanges** from different threads, as long as you have own context for each thread. In this case the DB is responsible for concurrency things.
What I don't understand, what the purpose of the code?
besides there is a possible race condition. In other words, the result is unpredictable.